# MySQL: Can't login after forgotten root password

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a CentOS Linux 8 machine with mysql Ver 8.0.26 I forgot the root user password tried to reset with the following commands

```
systemctl stop mysqld

mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

mysql

mysql> use mysql

mysql> update user set authentication_string = 'password' where User='root';

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I'm getting the following error on the log file:

```
2021-12-23T12:26:51.356204Z 22 [Warning] [MY-010319] [Server] Found invalid password for user: 'root@%'; Ignoring user
2021-12-23T12:26:51.356343Z 22 [Warning] [MY-010319] [Server] Found invalid password for user: 'root@localhost'; Ignoring user
```

What am I doing wrong?

--Update

I tried also:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

mysql

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

as suggested on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Still the same error on log file
and getting:

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
```

on console